# API versioning only when code changes

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I have a requirement, where we have to update a version of our API whenever any code change happens . In current situation our versioning follows major, minor, revision, build [i.e testjar-1.0.0.1.jar], but every time when build is triggered through jenkins, new jar file is created with new version number. but we have to restrict it to only when actual code change happens. please help how can we handle this.

Comment: stop calling release jobs on every build

Comment: What do you mean? git usually does not allow empty commits so if oyur build is only triggered by git you are already doing this.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta you can trigger build/release/... jobs through the Jenkins web-UI as well

Comment: yeah we can trigger build manually from Jenkins, and with every build version is incremented by 1. instead of this i want version to happen only when code changes. How can I make a logic for the same.

Comment: you'll have to look in the configuration of your jenkins build-job. probably you are triggering a release in there somewhere. don't know exactly how it's configured, but since you say it happens when you trigger the build in Jenkins, it's definitely something that happens within the Jenkins build

Comment: Yeah i too have a same understanding, but i have no understanding on jenkins. but yes I have a jenkins file in my project structure [can't share due to company policy], which reads some config.yml file and get the initial value of minor, major, revision and build and on top of this it increments the value by 1.

Comment: As we can see on jenkin's UI it shows number of commits once we trigger build, do we have any way to get the this num. in jenkins file so that we can make a flag and write logic around it.

Comment: @Stultuske, any idea ?

Comment: don't just look at the jenkins file in your project, look at the configuration of the build job in jenkins itself